# Не наследуется класс в IDEA, java

Tags: java

на начальном этапе изучения Java столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу унаследовать класс. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Вроде по всем урокам/курсам/книгам сходится, но у меня ошибка.

> Can't access com.company.Civil

Код:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Policeman cop = new Policeman();
        System.out.println(cop.getPayDay);
        System.out.println(cop.numOfWeekends);
    }
}

package com.company;

public class Civil{
    int payDay = 30000;
    int getPayDay(){
        return payDay;
    }
}

package com.company;
import com.company.Civil;

public class Policeman extends Civil {
    public int numOfWeekends = 20;
}
```

Comment: А структура каталогов в проекте какая? В какой папке лежит класс Civil?

Comment: В папке src/com.company/
Всё лежит рядом

Comment: Должно быть `src/com/company`

Comment: Проверил сейчас в проводнике так и есть, просто IDEA пишет src/com.company

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в вызове метода `getPayDay` (не хватает круглых скобок):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Policeman cop = new Policeman();
        System.out.println( cop.getPayDay() );  // <--
        System.out.println(cop.numOfWeekends);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это тоже, но у меня именно не наследуется Civil в классе Policeman

Comment: @ИванБелов Это единственная ошибка. Если структура каталогов действительно правильная, то всё должно компилироваться. https://dropmefiles.com/zT0HS

Comment: Это очень странно. Может у меня битый IDEA, но я попробую чуть позже сделать это на другой IDE, потому что ваша программа у меня запускается, но в классе Policeman так же выдаёт ошибку и в классе Main фраза getPayDay подсвечивается красным, очень странно.

Comment: @ИванБелов У меня IDEA 2021.1 Community Edition и Java 16.

Comment: Похоже ошибка в IDEA на моём компьютере. Установил Eclipse, всё слово в слово сделал и работает, а в IDEA нет. Попробую переустановить, может заработает, как то IDEA поудобнее)